# How to get all request headers list in ApiController's method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to get all request headers and its value from the requested API method. 
**Expected Output string Like below :**

```
*Cache-Control:no-cache,
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8,
HEADER_1:HEADER_VAL_1,
HEADER_2:HEADER_VAL_2,
HEADER_3:HEADER_VAL_3*
```

I have tried Request.Headers.toString() and also tried format output of this method;

```
//Code 
public class DEMOController : ApiController{

[HttpPost]
public string SaveSomeData(Object data)
{
string headersString = Request.Headers.toString();

}
}
```

Comment: Can you advise what output you actually get? This works as you expect it to when I test it (albeit without the commas separating). This corresponds with [the code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L221-L237) for it.

Comment: @John current I am getting   **Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: keep-alive Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Host: localhost:51161 User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2 HEADER_1: HEADER_VAL_1 HEADER_2: HEADER_VAL_2 HEADER_3: HEADER_VAL_3 Postman-Token: 3b13449f-6574-4028-a05e-493ee67b641d**      And I  am using  'Request.Headers.toString();'

Comment: OK and what is wrong with that? How is that different to your expected output?

Comment: Output displayed on HTML page not pretty, but I want pretty formatted output, and with comma separator, I can process data

Comment: Then you'll have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
    string strOutput = "";
    string[] TempStringArray;
    TempStringArray = Request.Headers.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
    for(int i = 0; i < TempStringArray.Length; i++)
    {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempStringArray[i]))
      {
         if (strOutput == "")
         {
            strOutput = strOutput + TempStringArray[i] + ",</br>";
         }
         else
        {
           strOutput = strOutput + TempStringArray[i] + ",</br>";
        }                         

     }
  }
```

**HTML OUTPUT:**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache,
Connection: keep-alive,
Accept: */*,
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate,
Host: localhost:51161,
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.16.3,
HEADER_1: HEADER_VAL_1,
HEADER_2: HEADER_VAL_2,
HEADER_3: HEADER_VAL_3
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit upon this requirement today.  My solution was slightly different as some of Deepak's logic didn't make sense to me (but not much does...).

I found this approach to be the one that most closely simulated the way [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) generates code.

```
var sb_debug = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var h in Request.Headers)
{
    if (h.Value != null)
    {
        var val = string.Join(",", h.Value); // Header value is IEnumerable<string>, not just a string value
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
        {
            sb_debug.AppendLine($"{h.Key}: {val}");
        }
    }
}

Debug.WriteLine(sb_debug.ToString()); // Outputs all headers and values
```

Note that there's no comma separators here because they aren't used with requests.